# How to stop Amazon Prime Day popups

Tags: safari, high-sierra, safari-extensions

My iMac runs High Sierra, and I use Safari. Both are fully updated.

This week, I am presented with recurring popups advertising Amazon Prime Day. I have cleared Safari's caches and cookies for all sites Amazon and Prime. "Block popups" is checked in Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data. Safari also runs the Safari extension Wipr, which is likewise up to date. Quits-and-restarts, both of the OS and Safari, are unavailing.

While the popups are easily dismissed, they're annoying. Other than these, I don't see popups or ads.

Have any of you ideas how I might successfully block them, or find their source?

Comment: This question is going to be irrelevant in <8 Hours.

Comment: True, but I might learn something in the meantime.

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker? Can you post the code from the pop up?

Comment: @JBis, yes Wipr is running on Safari. I don't know how to see the code from the popup. How do I do that?

Comment: Are these "Page Source" or "Page Resources" from the Develop menu?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: Are these pop-ups in the purest sense (i.e. an actual new Safari window) or an [HTML modal](https://binged.it/2LuO0mz) that show up in an existing window?

Comment: @Allan, I don't know what  "HTML modal" is. But what I see looks like the linked image, appearing on top of the previous Safari window. It is not a whole new Safari window.

Comment: The link I provided gives a sample.  But, if you're saying it doesn't open a new window, it's not a pop-up, but what I suspect is a modal (or a lightbox).  I don't use Safari; I use Firebox with the UBlock Origin plugin and I haven't seen a single Prime Day ad.  No configuration necessary.

Comment: @Allan I’m pretty sure it is a modal if my memory serves correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Download & Install [AdBlock](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.betafish.adblockforsafari-UAMUU4S2D9)
2. Right click on the popup and select "Block This Ad"
   [image]
3. Drag the slider until the popup is gone
4. Click "Looks Good"
   [image]

**Note:** Example of blocking Google logo on homepage